# AWS + Remmina on Ubuntu - Remmina goes into a loop trying to reconnect

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I followed [this article](https://datawookie.netlify.com/blog/2017/08/remote-desktop-on-an-ubuntu-ec2-instance/) to install xrdp on AWS Ubuntu 18 ec2 instance, and everything seemed to work properly for a few days.

However, now, when I try to connect to the EC2 instance using Remmina (from another Ubuntu computer) - Remmina goes into a loop, where it says "Reconnection in Progress.  Attempt 0 (or 1) out of 20."  ... then it goes back to 0, without getting past 2.

Any idea on how to get Remmina to work again?

Troubleshooting steps I tried:

1) Rebooting EC2

2) Rebooting laptop

3) SSHing into EC2 machine (this works just fine)

4) Restarting xrdp on target EC2 instance/reconnecting .  This did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue may have been two fold:

1) The password for the EC2 remote machine was note saved in Remmina (which was causing looping Behavior)

... once fixed - another issue came up - when logging in - only black screen would come up.  This was fixed by ssh0ing into the machine and running the following command:

```
echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
```

.. now everything seems to be working again.

Answer (score 1):

We had this looping behaviour on connection. We eventually discovered that the connection parameters was using the wrong colour depth.

We set **Colour depth = High Colour (16bpp)**, and it worked. It failed when we were using *256 colours (8bpp)*.

This is one of the configurations on the Basic tab.

I don't really know why this setting caused the looping behaviour, but this worked.

Comment: I have the same but the initial color depth was "Automatic (32 bpp) (Server chooses)". Switching to "High Color (16 bpp)" fixed the issue.